# How to plot a table of data without printing the table?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

So I'm having a little trouble with graphing from a table of data. So in a folder on my desktop, I have a ton of different LaTeX data tables that I converted from Microsoft Excel using Excel2LaTeX. Not only do I want to graph these data sets, but I would also like to hide the data tables on the actual document because, well, they're huge. I have a feeling I should be using the package `pgfplotstable`, but I am not sure how. I also don't know how to hide the table from the document and leave only the graph.

Example table:

```
 \begin{table}[htbp]
   \centering
   \caption{Air, Surface, and Bottom Temperature}
    \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
     Date  & Air (°C) & Surface (°C) & Bottom (°C) \\
    \midrule
    19-Sep-13 & 18.5  &       &  \\
    26-Sep-13 &       &       &  \\
    3-Oct-13 & 19.2  & 18.7  & 20.3 \\
   10-Oct-13 & 18.3  & 18.8  & 13 \\
   17-Oct-13 & 20.2  & 18.9  & 16 \\
   24-Oct-13 & 18.1  & 18.1  & 16.6 \\
   31-Oct-13 & 22.9  & 16.9  & 16 \\
   7-Nov-13 & 23    & 18.5  & 16 \\
   14-Nov-13 & 20.9  & 18.4  & 16.6 \\
   21-Nov-13 &       &       &  \\
   28-Nov-13 &       &       &  \\
   5-Dec-13 & 13.7  & 15.5  & 16.6 \\
   12-Dec-13 & 16.8  & 15.8  & 12.5 \\
   19-Dec-13 &       &       &  \\
   26-Dec-13 &       &       &  \\
   2-Jan-14 &       &       &  \\
   9-Jan-14 & 14.6  & 15.5  & 15 \\
   16-Jan-14 & 27.3  & 16    & 14.6 \\
   23-Jan-14 & 16.2  & 15.9  &  \\
   30-Jan-14 & 15.7  & 15.8  & 15 \\
   6-Feb-14 &       &       &  \\
   13-Feb-14 & 17.9  & 16    & 15 \\
   20-Feb-14 & 23.6  & 17.5  & 14.4 \\
   27-Feb-14 &       &       &  \\
   6-Mar-14 & 17.7  & 17.1  & 14.7 \\
   13-Mar-14 & 16.7  & 17.7  & 15.6 \\
   20-Mar-14 & 17.1  & 17.5  & 15.2 \\
   27-Mar-14 & 13.5  & 14.2  & 12 \\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
 \label{tab:addlabel}
\end{table}
```

Now it runs fine and the table shows up without error, but my main question is how do I both graph the data while omitting the table physically from the document?

Comment: Could you help us to help you adding a MWE for see what are you doing and therefore have a better idea of your problem.

Comment: Get rid of this table (completely delete it), put your data in text files (`data.dat`) and read the documentation to `pgfplots` on how to plot stuff. We can not help you with this little information. It is just to broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Date,Air,Surface,Bottom
19-Sep-13, 18.5,     ,
3-Oct-13 , 19.2, 18.7, 20.3
10-Oct-13, 18.3, 18.8, 13
17-Oct-13, 20.2, 18.9, 16
24-Oct-13, 18.1, 18.1, 16.6
31-Oct-13, 22.9, 16.9, 16
7-Nov-13 , 23  , 18.5, 16
14-Nov-13, 20.9, 18.4, 16.6
5-Dec-13 , 13.7, 15.5, 16.6
12-Dec-13, 16.8, 15.8, 12.5
9-Jan-14 , 14.6, 15.5, 15
16-Jan-14, 27.3, 16  , 14.6
23-Jan-14, 16.2, 15.9,
30-Jan-14, 15.7, 15.8, 15
13-Feb-14, 17.9, 16  , 15
20-Feb-14, 23.6, 17.5, 14.4
6-Mar-14 , 17.7, 17.1, 14.7
13-Mar-14, 16.7, 17.7, 15.6
20-Mar-14, 17.1, 17.5, 15.2
27-Mar-14, 13.5, 14.2, 12
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{data.csv}\datatable
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/xticklabels/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@xticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@xticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@x
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                width            = \linewidth, 
                grid             = major,
                xlabel           = Dates,
                ylabel           = Temperature ($^\circ$C),
                xticklabels      = {data.csv}{Date}{col sep=comma},
                xticklabel style = {rotate=90},
                xtick            = data,
            ]
            \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Air]{\datatable};
            \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Surface]{\datatable};
            \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Bottom]{\datatable};
            \legend{Air,Surface,Bottom}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]